# How to execute a query stored in a variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute queries in sqlyog which are

```
SET @adm_code = 12781;
SET @transfer = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM std_transfer_history AS sth
WHERE admission_code = @adm_code);
EXECUTE @transfer;
```

but it gives an error

```
Query: execute @transfer

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@transfer' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
```

So how can I'll get rid of....

Comment: I would suggest *checking the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax of* `EXECUTE`. For MySQL 5.7 that would be for example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html .

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `prepare` statement to execute a dynamic query.

```
// your transfer variable query ...

PREPARE stmt FROM @transfer;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: not working , It gives Query: EXECUTE stmt

Error Code: 1243
Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec